# When i want to read from a text file, some wrong characters appear in the end of my string?

Tags: c

I want to read the whole contents of a text file into a string. But at the end of my string, some more characters appears, which I don't want, following the correct contents. and the \0 I added seems lost.

```
char* 
textFileInput(char* filename)
{
char* text;
long lSize;
FILE *pf = fopen(filename, "r");
if (pf == NULL) return NULL;

fseek(pf,0,SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pf);
text = (char*)malloc(lSize+1);
rewind(pf); 
fread(text, sizeof(char), lSize, pf);
fclose(pf);

text[lSize] = '\0';//this sentence doesn't work well
return text;
}
```

[image] after '\n' is the wrong characters.

In windows this mistake will appear. when I run the code in linux , it seems working well.

Comment: When and where do you check the data in your debugger? Are you perhaps doing it *before* you write the null terminator?

Comment: How do you you have read all the bytes from the file without ***checking the return*** of `fread()`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fseek` followed by`ftell` counts the Windows newline as two bytes (because that's what it is).

But when you read the file it will translate the two-byte `\r\n` to plain newline `\n`.

Therefore the actual data in the buffer will seem shorter than the length you allocated, and you will set the null-terminator in the wrong position.

Always use the value returned by `fread` as the actual length, and use it to set the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guy's comment;
i check the return of "fread()" and find it is less than the variable "lSize" which i defined to sign the size of the file. i think the reason is that the end of file in Windows contents some special sign or the \r in \r\n doesn't read in but counted.
i change malloc into calloc which will automatically intialize the string , the porblem sovled then. i will be careful next-time.

Comment: fread doesnt care about line endings, your problem was that you did not have 0 at the end of you strings. calloc took care of that for you

Comment: actually，I add 0 at the end , but at the wrong end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `fseek` followed by`ftell` counts the Windows newline as two bytes (because that's what it is). But when you read the file it will translate the two-byte `\r\n` to plain newline `\n`.